# maxAllowedContentLength override

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis, web-config

I have the following setting in my root web.config:

```
<security>
  <requestFiltering>
    <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="20000000" />
  </requestFiltering>
</security>
```

I am trying to limit the size of POST requests to my pages to 1 KB in my web application. However, I want to do it without changing the above setting. Therefore, in web.config under Views folder, I added the below lines:

```
<security>
  <requestFiltering>
    <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="1000"/>
  </requestFiltering>
</security>
```

Which doesn't work, i.e my application still accepts POST requests with a large body. I tried the below settings unsuccessfully:

1. Using `<location>` tag (with allowOverride=true)
2. Timeouts and maxRequestLength attribute

My application still accepts requests with a large POST body (upto 20 MB - as specified in root web.config). Is there any workaround for this? Is it possible to do it programatically? I searched everywhere but couldn't find any examples.

Answer (score 1):

Try this: Add under `appSettings`

```
<add key="aspnet:MaxJsonDeserializerMembers" value="1024" />
```

Comment: Perhaps I should have elaborated more on the question. I am sending content in the HTTP POST Body of type x-www-form-urlencoded. Would this setting still be applicable?